# How to put global functions which access non-global classes all in one place?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, global

I might not even be posing the question correctly, but here's my situation.  I have a namespace into which I want to put all of my global functions.  I want to define them all in the corresponding .cpp file.  Many of these functions access instances of non-global classes, which may or may not be themselves members of the namespace.  I can forward-declare the classes, but I will of course still get linker errors when I try to invoke the class methods.  One (terrible-seeming) solution is to define each of these globals *after* the corresponding classes have been defined, but this puts different functions in different files and I want to avoid this at all costs, doing this seems deeply wrong.

What else can I do?  I guess I'm having a conceptual issue here, what sort of design strategies might help resolve this?  Do I have to make them static members of the corresponding classes?  I don't like this b/c my classes have long names but my namespace name is short... so just use a typedef?  But conceptually these are global functions, so I would like to keep them that way...  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `#include`-ing the classes' header files into your "global" source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't mark a comment as the answer, so I'll just post it myself--basically Oli Charnesworth was right, refactoring was the solution.  There was a particular class which was causing my circular dependencies problem, and I just redid things so that it no longer depended on the 'global' info, rather the 'global' info #included it.

Answer (score 2):

I would define the "global functions" in their own header file, on their own.  If you need to add forward declarations, do so there.

In the .cpp file, just include the headers for the other "non-global" classes and functions as needed.  This will keep the public API "clean" (the header file), while letting you develop normally in the actual code for these functions.

Comment: Is including the *.h files enough?  It seems odd since these *.h files themselves must #include the *.h file in which the global namespace is declared.  Anyway I will try this out tonight (and post again), thanks.

Comment: @Matt: Yes.  The header files should be guarded, so the types will only be included once.  Forward declarations take care of the circular referencing...

Comment: @Matt: If you have classes that rely on a library of global functions that in turn rely on those classes, it sounds like you may have a design problem.  Consider refactoring...

Comment: @Oli, you are probably right--though of course the global functions upon which a given class relies, and the global functions which rely on that class, are different.  Fortunately my program is still small enough to make refactoring practical so I will see.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Oli Charlesworth can you just `#include` the respective class headers in your global-methods source file?